# Overcoming 'this form has expired' error when posting data to an EE template

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

When POSTing data to an ExpressionEngine template, EE returns the well known `This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.`-error.

I am trying to post JSON data to the template. The template contains a custom EE module tag that should further handle the incoming data. Both empty request bodies as POSTing actual data return the same error.

I have tried generating an XID using the {XID_HASH} variable. Sending the XID hash in the POST request does not change anything, the error persists.

How can I make the EE template accept the incoming POST request?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you try at SE-EE? https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/31403/post-to-ee-template-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by changing the setup. I realised that posting data to a template is an anti pattern -- data should be posted to EE actions instead.

So I modified my module so that it inserts a new action on installation:

> (in upd.module_name.php):

```
$act = array(
    'class'     => 'Module_name' ,
    'method'    => 'receive_post_data'
);

ee()->db->insert('actions', $act);
```

This way I can post data to the newly generated action url, for instance https://example.com/index.php?ACT=123

EE will then call the supplied method in your addon file.

> (in mod.module_name.php):

```
public function receive_post_data()
{
    // Do things with $_POST['whatever_your_posting']
}
```

When posting data, you need to supply a csrf_token in the body of the request. The csrf_token can be generated in the template / origin of the post data using either the `{XID_HASH}` or `{csrf_token}` variables.